Scroll View scrollBounceBehaviour not working correctly
I have a ScrollView inside a NavigationStack, and the toolbar is making the scroll view bounce even when the view is fully in the screen, and I don't want this to happen. I tried moving the modifier for scrollBounceBehavior to different places but it didn't help.
NavigationStack {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 25) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text("Add a Pet")
                            .poppinsBold(size: 20)
                        
                        RoundedTextField("What is your pets name?", text: $name)
                            .focused($focusedField)
                    }
                    
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("Which type of pet do you have?")
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        
                        HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            ForEach(Species.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { species in
                                AnimalType(species: species, selectedSpecies: $petSpecies)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text("What is your pets gender?")
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(Gender.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { gender in
                                GenderCard(gender: gender, selectedGender: $gender)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                    
                    RoundedTextField("What is your pets breed?", text: $breed)
                        .focused($focusedField)
                    
                    Button("Save") {
                        loadingState = .loading
                        Task {
                            if let petSpecies = petSpecies, let gender = gender {
                                try await vm.createPet(id: UUID().uuidString, name: name, species: petSpecies, gender: gender, breed: breed)
                            }
                            loadingState = .idle
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(ConfirmButtonStyle())
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .disabled(!formIsValid || loadingState == .loading)
                    
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 50)
                }
                .padding(.top, 35)
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            
            if loadingState == .loading {
                LoadingView(text: "Saving...", fullScreen: false)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Screen tapped")
            focusedField = false
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button {
                    focusedField = false
                    dismiss()
                    print("Button tapped")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            }
        }
    }

Also would it be recommended to split up the view into smaller components, for eg, one component for the species section, one for the gender section etc. or would that be unnecessary.

As a workaround, you could consider using ViewThatFits. This can contain 2 versions of the body content: (1) the content by itself and (2) the same content but wrapped in a ScrollView. The scrollable version will only get used if the first version doesn't fit.

@BenzyNeez I tried using ViewThatFits with 1) just content, and 2) the content wrapped in a ScrollView, but the scroll bounce is still there.

Fixed the issue by just reducing the spacing of the initial VStack
